# How to route data from fluentd to influxdb running on remote server (influx server)?

Tags: python, influxdb, fluentd

I have a set up where I read a sensor data from my python script running on Raspberry pi. I want to store the sensor readings on my influxdb. I have an account in influxdb where I have created a database.

I am redirecting the data coming from my sensor to "fluentd". So, my data from sensor is coming to fluentd which is also running on my raspberry pi. Right now, I output the data coming to "fluentd" to "stdout" and can see the data on console. So, this is working fine. Now i want to route this data to my "influxdb". I am not able to figure out how to achieve this: My current fluentd conf file looks like this:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>
<match fluentd.test.**>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

can someone please suggest me how to configure to send the data to my influxdb database. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install influxdb plugin for fluentd:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-influxdb
```

After that you can easily achive it using such config:

```
<match fluentd.test.**>                     
    type copy                                
    <store>                                  
      type file                              
      path /var/log/td-agent/influxdb/log    
    </store>
  <store>
    type influxdb
    dbname <dbname>
    user <username if needs>
    password <password if needs>
    flush_interval 10
    host <influxdb_server_name>
    port 8086
  </store>
</match>
```

First part (store) needs to verify data that you send to influx. You can remove this part if you want.

Answer (score 0):

*For InfluxDB 2.x(https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-plugin-fluent), install:
fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-influxdb-v2 -v 1.9.0

*For InfluxDB 1.x instances(https://github.com/fangli/fluent-plugin-influxdb), install:
fluent-gem install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30537534)